# Copying and Pasting does not copy the cell borders in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, copy, border

I am unable to copy the entire cell including all borders and paste it onto the adjacent cell.
The original sheet is shown in 1.jpg
I want to delete P1 from row 18. When this is done U2 will remove to column G along with its border formatting. But I see a blue bottom border in Column G as shown in 2.jpg
The expected result is shown in 3.jpg

```vb
 For col_num = col_num To 12
                                        
    'MsgBox stored_row & col_num
                                        
                                       
         If col_num = 12 Then
            Exit For
         End If
        
            If Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num + 1).Value <> "" Then
                
                Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num + 1).Copy
                Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num).PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num + 1).Value = ""
            
            ElseIf Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num + 1).Value = "" Then
                
                Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num + 1).Copy
                Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row, col_num).PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False

                'Exit For
            End If
            
            If Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row - 1, col_num).Value <> "" Then
                    Cells(stored_row, col_num).Select
                        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                            .Color = vbBlue
                            .TintAndShade = 0
                            .Weight = xlThick
                        End With
            End If
             If Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row + 1, col_num).Value <> "" Then
                    Cells(stored_row, col_num).Select
                        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                            .Color = vbBlue
                            .TintAndShade = 0
                            .Weight = xlThick
                        End With
            End If
            
Next
```

I am unable to copy the entire cell including all borders and paste it onto the adjacent cell.

The original sheet is shown in 1.jpg I want to delete P1 from row 18. When this is done U2 will remove to column G along with its border formatting.

[image]

But I see a blue bottom border in Column G as shown in 2.jpg

[image]

The expected result is shown in 3.jpg

[image]

Comment: Maybe you need an `Else` block to this `If Sheets("DSS").Cells(stored_row + 1, col_num).Value <> ""` to set `.LineStyle = xlNone`

Comment: Perhaps this is working correctly the cell borders need to be set for the cell you are copying. You can not copy the border from the cell below it.

Comment: cell borders can "belong" to the cell below, above, right or left - in this case the border will not be copied.

Answer (score 0):

This might give you a way to do what you want:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Shift_Value_and_Borders_Left()
    Dim targetCell As Range, sourceCell As Range, x As Integer

    Set targetCell = Range("G18")
    Set sourceCell = targetCell.Offset(0, 1)
    
    targetCell.Value = sourceCell.Value
        
    For x = 5 To 12
        targetCell.Borders(x).LineStyle = sourceCell.Borders(x).LineStyle
        targetCell.Borders(x).Weight = sourceCell.Borders(x).Weight
        targetCell.Borders(x).Color = sourceCell.Borders(x).Color
    Next x

    Set sourceCell = Nothing
    Set targetCell = Nothing
End Sub
```